# GWT 2.1 in UiBinder put Cell Widgets

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2, gwt-mvp

How does it work?

I see no tags defined for example to add a CellTable in a UiBinder.ui.xml file, like

The documentation is sparse on this.

So if it doesnt work, where should I put the cell widgets, in the uiBinder class or the presenter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look in the Expenses sample provided with GWT 2.1.0.

Basically you need to add to the `<ui:Binder` tag:

```
xmlns:c='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client'
```

and then use it for example as:

```
<c:CellTable
      addStyleNames='{desktop.table}'
      width='100%'
      ui:field='table' />
```

This is from the `ExpenseReportList` class.

Ui widgets should not go in the Presenter. The celltabel has interfaces to communicate the data between presenter and view.

Comment: Oh. Thank you, I forgot the to add the <ui:Binder tag for ..cellview.client.

Comment: +1. Silly mistake on my part. I had forgotten to add the namespace for cell widgets. Thanks.